# Kubernetes deployment Error: unknown flag: --replicas issue

Tags: kubernetes

While creating a deployment using command

```
kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx:1.7.8 --replicas=2 --port=80
```

I am getting error `Error: unknown flag: --replicas`

```
controlplane $ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:58:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:50:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
controlplane $ kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx:1.7.8 --replicas=2 --port=80
Error: unknown flag: --replicas
See 'kubectl create deployment --help' for usage.
```

Could anyone please help me with the reason for this as this command is working on other Kubernetes clusters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like that `--replicas` and `--port` flags were added in version `1.19` based on the [`v1-19` release notes](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/) and that's why you are seeing the error.

So, you need the minimum version `1.19` to able to use the `replicas` and `port` flags as part of the `kubectl create deployment` command.

You can however use the `kubectl scale/expose` command after creating the deployment.

Relevant PR links for [`replicas`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/91562) and [`port`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/91113).

Comment: I'm seeing this error with kubectl 1.23

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77392666/1461862

Comment: minikube kubectl -- deploy nginx  --replicas=10........

Answer (score 11):

You may try to put a blank character between -- and the commands
For example

kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx:1.7.8 -- replicas=2

It's work for me.

Comment: Before:
 kubectl run nginx --image=nginx:1.15.12-alpine --generator=run-pod/v1

After:

 kubectl run nginx --image=nginx:1.15.12-alpine -- generator=run-pod/v1

Thanks!!!

Comment: it worked for me.. why does this happen?

Comment: This is bad advice, the keywords after `--` are part of the "command". Putting `replicas=2` there only sets the variable "replicas" in the container's shell, which has no effect

Comment: nope then it goes as a command
```Error: failed to start container "my-nginx": Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "replicas=3": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown```

Answer (score 1):

This happend to me and I'm using version 1.27.2 the issue is related to the character used for the double hyphen --. I was using an en-dash (–) instead of two regular hyphens (-). In command-line interfaces, you need to use two regular hyphens -- for specifying flags.

Answer (score -1):

if you trying to update the replica parameter in Azure release pipeline inside the help upgrade command then refer to the following link
[Overriding Helm chart values](https://all.docs.genesys.com/PrivateEdition/Current/PEGuide/HelmOverrides)

here it explains that you can override the parameters inside the vallues.yaml file with set command like this

```
helm upgrade $(RELEASE_ENV) --install  \
infravc/manifests/helm/web \
--set namespace=$(NAMESPACE) \
--set replicas=$(replicas) \
--set replicasMax=$(replicasMax) \
--set ingress.envSuffix=$(envSuffix) \
--set ENV.SECRET=$(appSecretNonprod) \
--set ENV.CLIENT_ID=$(clientIdNonprod) \
```